# callback function on close in video lightbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I download and using video light box free version from http://videolightbox.com/ for my local website. It work pretty good for me, however, I want to customize my light box video by putting a black background of opacity 80% but I cannot remove this background on closing video light box.

As I inspected the element, I found the close button of the video light box was `a.close` so I called it using jquery like this

```
$("a.voverlay").click(function(){       // calling a video light box
    $("div#theatre").show();    
});
$("a.close").click(function(){ // closing a video light box
   alert("hello video");
   $("div#theatre").css("display","none");
});
```

But nothing happened on close event.

So, any advice, thanks.

Comment: It may be that `a.close` is not present in the DOM until the overlay appears. In this case, your event binds to nothing. Instead, look into event delegation, which circumvents this problem.

Comment: yes, as Utkanos said, try changing your click handler to something like this `$(document).on("click", "a.close", function(){` .

Comment: @Utkanos, thanks. First I also suspected like that too that the element was disappeared immediately on closing, but I as I looked more deeper, I found its script was reside in `jquery.tools.min.js:39`, so I went to edit it to prevent it closing and test my function again but still nothing happened. its script is `<a class="close"></a>` and its background image.

Comment: @DexterHuinda @Utkanos, yes thank you for your tips. Now it works fine by changing it to `$(document).on("click","a.close",function(){})`

Comment: @HouyNarun no problem, cheers to Utkanos tips